# how to read a file from form-Data in an AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, form-data

I am trying to send a PDF or text file to an AWS Lambda function (Node JS). I'd like to be able to process this file in the lambda function. I know often the best practice is to use a trigger function from an s3 bucket. However, I'd like to be able to send this lambda function a file from formdata, extract information from the file and then return the extracted info back.

I have been able to first encode the file in 64 bit binary data and send it to AWS lambda via a JSON, but often when I try to decode the file (especially a PDF) in the Lambda Function it is corrupted or empty.

Image files seem to work well for this type of encoding, but been unsuccessful with PDFs. Any help greatly appreciated. Rather then encode in base 64 is there a way I can obtain the file from a formdata? My code is below:

```
export const handler = async(event) => {
   
    console.log("event", event)
    
    var converted = atob(event.body) // RATHER HOW WOULD I READ A FILE FROM FORMDATA



     const response =  {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {"Content-Type":"text/html", //"application/pdf", // "multipart/form-data", //
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token"
                        
        },
        "body": event,
        "isBase64Encoded": true
        }
        
    return response;
};
```

thanks so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are using an API gateway to trigger the lambda function. In that case, you have to enable `multipart/form-data` in API gateway as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html). The gist of the documentation is as follows:

1. In the **Settings** pane, choose **Add Binary Media Type** in the
   **Binary Media Types** section. Type a required media type, for example, `image/png`, in the input text field.
2. Add `Content-Type` and `Accept` to the request headers for your proxy method.
3. Add those same headers to the integration request headers.
4. Deploy the API

PS: If you are using Lambda Proxy integration ({proxy+}, just steps 1 and 4 are enough.